# Get youtube channel data in array

Tags: php, youtube-data-api, php-curl

i am trying to get Youtube channel data with that api

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics&id={ Channel Id }&key={ API }
```

I used that code to fetch the data

```
    if( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == 'GET' && !empty( $_GET ) ){

    $channel_id = $_GET[ 'channel_id' ];

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics&id=". $channel_id ."&key=AIzaSyCKAnI41bI4UGDJgYUcwrhrIfnjoD3uirM",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }

}

?>
<form id="channelIdForm" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Type channel id" name="channel_id" id="channelId" />
    <button type="submit">Get data</button>

</form>
```

And it appeared like that

```
{ "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse", "etag": "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/pss5QFB6saoevVwzX-8y6f1U75E\"", "pageInfo": { "totalResults": 1, "resultsPerPage": 1 }, "items": [ { "kind": "youtube#channel", "etag": "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/gPFze0Hh7eRu9O5tXiTBVyvCwa8\"", "id": "UC4QYTjhWMxiC6UwvKLVkDDA", "snippet": { "title": "حفيد برايز حفيد برايز", "description": "", "publishedAt": "2018-04-01T17:18:31.000Z", "thumbnails": { "default": { "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-wuTRH4WK_UA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ms_Qpu4ekLk/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg", "width": 88, "height": 88 }, "medium": { "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-wuTRH4WK_UA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ms_Qpu4ekLk/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg", "width": 240, "height": 240 }, "high": { "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-wuTRH4WK_UA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ms_Qpu4ekLk/s800-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg", "width": 800, "height": 800 } }, "localized": { "title": "حفيد برايز حفيد برايز", "description": "" } }, "contentDetails": { "relatedPlaylists": { "uploads": "UU4QYTjhWMxiC6UwvKLVkDDA", "watchHistory": "HL", "watchLater": "WL" } }, "statistics": { "viewCount": "830460", "commentCount": "0", "subscriberCount": "3741", "hiddenSubscriberCount": false, "videoCount": "19" } } ] }
```

Then i tried to convert that json to an array to pick what i want from it with index

So i tried that instead of $response

```
$json = $response;                                 
  $arr = json_decode($json, true);              
  $row = array_reduce($arr['items'], function($c, $v){
      $c[ key($v) ] = current($v);
      return $c;
  }, array());

  print_r( $row );
```

I expected to see all the indexes below item but the result was

```
Array ( [kind] => youtube#channel )
```

It show just kind i don't know what the problem with so if any one can help i will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array_reduce` function reduces an array to a single value. But it appears you are interested in multiple key/value pairs. Since `json_decode($json, true);` already provides you with an associated array you can retrieve specific keys via their names. Example:

```
$arr = json_decode($response, true);
$newArray = [];
$requiredKeys = ['kind','etag'];
foreach ($requiredKeys as $key){
      $newArray[$key] = $arr[$key];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nadav that what am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It is a very-multi-dimensional array.

Here's some code that prints the contents of an array.  If the value it is going to print is an array, it calls itself again.  You'll see it puts out `Printing $json_arr[items[0][statistics] :` followed by a bunch of key->value pairs, so you can find the state you want and you'll know what the parent array(s) are.

```
<?php

$json='{ "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse", "etag": "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/pss5QFB6saoevVwzX-8y6f1U75E\"", "pageInfo": { "totalResults": 1, "resultsPerPage": 1 }, "items": [ { "kind": "youtube#channel", "etag": "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/gPFze0Hh7eRu9O5tXiTBVyvCwa8\"", "id": "UC4QYTjhWMxiC6UwvKLVkDDA", "snippet": { "title": "حفيد برايز حفيد برايز", "description": "", "publishedAt": "2018-04-01T17:18:31.000Z", "thumbnails": { "default": { "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-wuTRH4WK_UA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ms_Qpu4ekLk/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg", "width": 88, "height": 88 }, "medium": { "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-wuTRH4WK_UA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ms_Qpu4ekLk/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg", "width": 240, "height": 240 }, "high": { "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-wuTRH4WK_UA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ms_Qpu4ekLk/s800-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg", "width": 800, "height": 800 } }, "localized": { "title": "حفيد برايز حفيد برايز", "description": "" } }, "contentDetails": { "relatedPlaylists": { "uploads": "UU4QYTjhWMxiC6UwvKLVkDDA", "watchHistory": "HL", "watchLater": "WL" } }, "statistics": { "viewCount": "830460", "commentCount": "0", "subscriberCount": "3741", "hiddenSubscriberCount": false, "videoCount": "19" } } ] } ';

$json_arr=json_decode($json,true);

function print_array($prefix,$arr){
    print("printing ".$prefix." :\n");
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            print_array($prefix."[".$k."]",$v);
        }else{
            print("key: ".$k."   value:".$v." \n");
        }
    }
    return;
}

print_array("\$json_arr",$json_arr);

?>
```